# What would happen in PowerApps if the browser is closed?

Tags: session, timer, powerapps

I will have access to the Papps licence soon but I cant stop thiking about this, imagine I have a timer on powerapps that will close the app if the user didnt do anything for about 10 minutes.
Will the timer trigger its events if the user closes the browser window or kill the powerapp process in the cellphone?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Will the timer trigger its events if the user closes the browser window or kill the powerapp process in the cellphone---> No it will not trigger Timer event. (as per my understanding)

Comment: Have you tested it? I think the apps run on the server.